# Chima Speedorz game -- how to play?

Tags: chima

Lego Chima Speedorz sets include cryptic instructions on how to play the game, but I'm unable to fully understand them. I'm looking for a comprehensive answer or guide that details the game rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might help you, its a pretty nice writeup on how to play:
http://thebrickblogger.com/2013/01/lego-legends-of-chima-speedorz-game/